# Is mixed model a right method to apply?

Tags: mixed-model

*I have a data set including four variables (ID,Time, group, result) in the following format. I want to see if the result (such as Calcium) change over time in different group or not. I was wondering what is the right statistical model to use? Can I use two way mixed anova for this analysis?*

```
> Id     time   group     Result 
  1        0       0      
  1        1       0
  1        2       0
  2        0       1
  2        1       1
  2        2       1
  3        0       0
  3        1       0
  3        2       0
```

*Also, I am confused between choosing **aov with Error(ID/Time)** and **lmer with (Time|ID)**? Which one I need to choose?*

Answer (score 4):

In case you have a balanced design in which all subjects only have measurements on specific time points, and provided that you have a moderate number of subjects, the best you could do is to fit a marginal model with an unstructured covariance matrix, e.g., using function `gls()` from package **nlme**. In your case, something like

```
fm <- gls(Result ~ time * group, data = <your_data>, correlation = corSymm(form = ~ 1 | Id), weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | time))

summary(fm)
```

Comment: What is the required number of repeats in order to use gls? Forexample, can I use it if I have more than 3 time points in my data set? Also do I need to check the Sphericity assumption if I want to apply your suggestion?